# How can I bridge across a change in differential impedance?

Tags: differential, signal-integrity, high-speed, termination, lvds

In a design I'm working on, I have a 100Mbps differential signal traveling from a chip on one PCB to a chip on another PCB. For various reasons, I can't make the differential impedance the same on both boards.

Looking at the signal on a 'scope, I can see that the waveform looks quite bad, presumably due to reflections at the change of impedance.

Is there a component I can use to help the signal cross this impedance change without reflecting?

My thought was that either a balun or an LVDS repeater might do the job.

Alternatively, could I replace the parallel termination resistor at the end of the line with a series termination at the start of the line? This would absorb reflections coming back from the impedance changes (but obviously wouldn't do anything for double reflections, although those should be much weaker arriving at the end).

Comment: need more details - What are the two impedance levels? Signal levels?

Comment: May be as simple as an additional termination at the impedance mismatch. As Neil says, not enough details.

Comment: @Neil_UK - There are actually 3 PCBs in sequence. One is apparently incalculable according to Saturn PCB. One  is 75R, the last is 100R.

Comment: @user_1818839 - Can you give an example of this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_pad#Impedance_matching

Comment: OK, we're hooked. What are the incalculable line's dimensions? What makes you or Saturn PCB think it's incalculable? There's not much difference between 75 and 100, you ought to be able to get away with connecting those, even if it's not perfect.

Comment: @Neil_UK - it's nothing really interesting. It's not a meta material or anything. But Saturn gives a warning and calculates a negative impedance. I think it's because the distance to the reference plane is just 25 microns, while the tracks are 220 microns.

Comment: If you have design control then  match the track width/depth to 2:1 not 9:1 which is  too low an impedance (excessive C) Then match the interface cable and load to same . What's the real problem?  Power loss? Then increase the height to gnd plane.

Comment: You could try a back termination resistor, in addition to the parallel termination, but you need to model/simulate that.  I've done that on some LVDS designs where stubs were causing reflections.  But my speed was down around 20 MHz, much slower than your speed.

Comment: @SteveSh - I'm not sure how to simulate that, because I'm not sure what the impedance is on one of the boards.

Comment: In case you didn't know 2:1 w:h ought to yield close to 50 Ohms ballpark  9:1 will be close to 10 ohms , which can be easily modelled and simulated in Falstad to match your photo's if you offered all the xyz Dk geometric specs and photo with IC's

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - it's really not necessary at this stage to know the exact impedance.  You know one is 75 ohms, and another is 50 ohms.  The third one is a lot lower than the other two because of the line width and height above the return plane.  Whether it's 30, 20, or 15 ohms probably doesn't matter much for this experiment.